# About open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y\subset X$. Give an example where $A$ is open in $Y$ but not open in $X$.
Give an example where $A$ is closed in $Y$ but not closed in $X$.

Since $Y\subset X$, how can $A$ be open in $Y$ but not in $X$? The same for the second statement.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ Y = [0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R} = X $. Then let $ A = [0,1) $ for both questions.

A subspace topology may not be a subset of its parent topology. Hence, sets that are open/closed in a subspace topology may not be open/closed in its parent topology.

Comment: I’m assuming the standard topology on $ \mathbb{R} $, of course.

Comment: what does "in" mean? That is what do we mean when we say "open in $X$", rather than say "open"?

Comment: Consider the example you gave, why did you choose $A=Y$? Is this the only way to give such an example?

Comment: ‘In’ means ‘with respect to’. The open subsets of $ Y $ in this case are the intersection of $ Y $ with open subsets of $ X $. This is why we get intervals of the form $ [0,b) $ that are open in $ Y $ but are not open in $ X $. I could have chosen $ A = \left[ 0,\frac{1}{2} \right) $, which is open in $ Y $ but not in $ X $, or $ A = \left[ \frac{1}{2},1 \right) $, which is closed in $ Y $ but not in $ X $.

Answer (score 1):

This is to answer the question you asked in your comment: “What does "in" mean?".

Sets are not open or closed on their own.  A topological space is equipped with a topology, which is a choice about which sets are open and which are closed.  If the topology is different, the open sets will be different.  So you can't say that a set is open or closed without knowing what topological space is being discussed.

For example $R$ with the usual topology and $R$ with the indiscrete topology are two different topological spaces, and the subset $(0,1)$ is open in the first space and not open in the second.

Now consider these two spaces: $R$ with the usual topology, and $[0,1]$ with the usual topology.  $[0,1]$ is a subset of both spaces.  It is not open in the first space, as you know.  But it is open in the second space, because it is the whole space, and the whole space is always open.